# Why is mongo return zero matching document although there is one?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, find, unique

I have an app which asks users to pick up a username. I want to make all usernames unique so write something like that.

```
var uniqueUsername = false;
MongoPlayerData playerDB = new MongoPlayerData();
var nickCheck = Query.EQ("UserName", myUsername);
uniqueUsername = playerDB.PlayerInfo.Find(nickCheck).Count() == 0;
if(uniqueUsername){//Do something...}
```

This is the logic but some users can get the same username. How it is possible. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be since there is no constraint in place for that field/property in document and also `MongoDB` have no support for `transaction` (it just that it supports atomic operation). Thus, if you are inserting document on multiple threads then it's possible to have so.  Instead you should try checking against the `_id` field to make sure the uniqueness of the document. If you really want to make sure that the `UserName` field must be unique across the documents likewise `_id` field then try creating a [`unique index`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on it.

```
db.PlayerInfo.createIndex( { "UserName": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Comment: I have already an index "Username" and cannot remembers what I set for unique field how can i check is it created as unique or not.@Rahul

Comment: @ÇağatayKaya, well if it's allowing duplicates then definitely you haven't created an unique index on it.

Comment: Ok how can I update unique field of my database and Is there any problem occurs because of duplicated fields?

Comment: @ÇağatayKaya, depends on your application need. if you want that field to be unique then go for it else probably ok. about the other question please post another question for that.

Comment: ok I get my answer. Cannot create an unique index if db have duplicates.

Comment: @ÇağatayKaya, consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still want to know how my search return zero results @Rahul